# Connecting client and server in python the code below dont give output make browser busy

Tags: python, sockets, chat

This code is not giving output it just makes the browser busy. Any idea why?

```
import socket    
s = socket.socket() 
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345               
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
print (s.recv(1024))
s.close 


import socket             
s=socket.socket()         
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345                
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))         
s.listen(5)                 
while True:
c,addr = s.accept()     
print ('Got connection from', addr)
c.send('Thank you for connecting')
c.close()
```

Comment: `s.close()`, not `s.close`.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

client program:

```
import socket
f=open("hello.txt","r").read()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
port = 12345               
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
s.sendall(str.encode(f))
print (s.recv(1024).decode('ascii'))
s.close()
```

server program:

```
import socket               
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
print ("Socket successfully created")
port = 12345               
s.bind(('', port))        
print ("socket binded to %s" %(port))
f=open("hi.txt","r").read()
s.listen(5)     
print ("socket is listening")
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   print ('Got connection from', addr)
   print (c.recv(1024).decode('ascii'))
   c.sendall(str.encode(f))
   c.close()
```

server output:

```
Socket successfully created
socket binded to 12345
socket is listening
Got connection from ('127.0.0.1', 51630)
helloooooo
```

client output:

```
hiiiii
```

Open the two programs in seperate shells.
Run server program first then client program.
Dont close the server program before running client program.
Create two files one for server and one for client.
Read the data from those files and send it.
While receiving the data decode it and print it.
You can send entire data from files or just a single line it depends on you.
To know more about reading,writing and creating files you can refer https://docs.python.org/release/3.6.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files
Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: what do u want exactly?do u want the client to send a text that it has read from file? or a server to send a text read from file?

Comment: how can i do that for both like server reads hi from file and sends it to client and client reads hello from file and sends it to server in response